# Reading private keys from oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, pki

We use Oracle wallet for scripting Oracle releases.

Using mkstore I can add or delete private keys to Oracle wallet.

Either using Java or C#, I want to read the private key sitting inside the Oracle wallet.

Could someone share the sample code how to do that.

This post explains how to open a wallet using Java, but it does not read the private key.
http://blog.mikesidoti.com/2007/04/opening-oracles-wallet.html

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the point of the wallet to prevent anything from reading the private key?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out priv.key -in wallet\ewallet.p12

I found it on this blog post: [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://ilmarkerm.blogspot.com/2012/05/extracting-private-key-from-oracle.html&ei=eEbIUPOVJoPQtAbRqoCoDg&usg=AFQjCNFsKtHrHCvlguWqgwyuAxwN-De0AQ&sig2=9Fn342v16U2swBsiDzCrmQ&cad=rja)